# Show $\int_0^\infty xe^{-ax^2}dx=\frac{1}{2a}$

Tags: integration

I tried integrating by parts but I always arrive at an expression other than $\frac{1}{2a}$ which contains $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$ from the Gaussian integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2}dx=\frac12 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$. Is there some kind of trick to evaluating this integral?

Comment: Let $-ax^2=u$..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: let $u=ax^2$.  Then $1/2du=axdx$.

Comment: $1/2du=axdx$ I think.

Comment: @MyGlasses, thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

$\int_0^{+\infty}xe^{-ax^2}dx=\frac{1}{-2a}\int_0^{+\infty}-2axe^{-ax^2}dx=\frac{1}{-2a}[e^{-ax^2}]_0^{+\infty}=\frac{1}{2a}$

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $x^2=y$. Then
$$\int_0^\infty xe^{-ax^2}\,dx=\frac12\int_0^\infty e^{-ay}\,dy.$$

Answer (score -4):

This integral is very simple and can be explained and understood in a better way just using simple properties of Gamma function
Put $$ax^2 =z$$ then use the definition of Gamma function also $$\Gamma \frac{1}{2}=\sqrt{\pi}$$

Comment: No need to switch to polar coordinates, switch only if you know the topic with complete understanding

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem being asked.

Comment: I am just giving him information so that he could solve the question on his own

Comment: But your information doesn't help.  You didn't read the problem carefully.

Comment: Gamma function is not required.  This is a simple substitution integral.